# Wrong Intent getting used

Tags: android, android-intent

UPDATE: It seems like in my ActivityCentresPage it isn't getting the correct intent. Is there a special way I need to get the intent from a notification?

I added a new key to my intent, and my ActivityCentresPAge displays it as null, even though there is a value. What intent is my Activity getting?

I'm building my Receiver to handle GCM messages, and some Intents aren't working.

Here's my code

```
private Intent getIntent(String action, JSONObject obj) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    if (action.equals("home")) {
        intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    }
    else if (action.equals("view_timetable")) {
        intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityViewTimetable.class);
    }
    else if (action.equals("invite_friends")) {
        intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityInviteFriends.class);
    }
    else if (action.startsWith("venue_")) {
        try {
            intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityCentrePage.class);
            Log.d("FUApp", obj.getString("name"));
            BaseActivity bAct = new BaseActivity();
            intent.putExtra(bAct.ExtraKeyCentreName, obj.getString("name"));
            intent.putExtra(bAct.ExtraKeyCentreDist, "Not Available");
            intent.putExtra(bAct.ExtraKeyCentreJSON, obj.toString());
            intent.putExtra(bAct.ExtraKeyCentrePostcode, "none");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("FUApp", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    else if (action.equals("")) {
        //intent = new Intent(ctx, .class);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    }
    return intent;
}
```

And

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivityMain.class);
    if (to_load_action != null) {
        intent = getIntent(to_load_action, to_load_obj);
    }

    for (int a = 0;a < todo_items.length();a++) {
        JSONObject todo_item = new JSONObject();
        String action = "";
        String miniAction = "";
        try {
            todo_item = todo_items.getJSONObject(a);
            action = todo_item.getString("action");
            miniAction = todo_item.getString("action_title");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("FUApp", e.getMessage());
        }
        Intent intent2 = getIntent(action, todo_item);
        PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent2, 0);
        mBuilder.addAction(0, miniAction, pIntent2);
    }

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
```

When the to_load_action and action (in the for loop) both start with venue_ when I click on the main notification, the intent from addAction is called.

Can anyone see what I've got wrong here?

EDIT: This line

```
Log.d("FUApp", obj.getString("name"));
```

Outputs the correct information, so two different sets of data are being passed to the method. Also, if the to_load_action doesn't start with venue_, and the action in the for loop does, everything works fine.

Comment: I believe my issue is in my ActivityCentresPage not getting the correct intent, I'm looking into why now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted the problem by giving each PendingIntent a new ID, I believe the problem ws the PendingIntent's where being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

in pendingIntent should't you use flags ?

```
    PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent2, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

or this

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Comment: this is answer or question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an answer.

Comment: When I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK the main notification doesn't do anything, and when using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT I get the same issue as before. If the to_load_action doesn't start with venue_, and the action in the for loop does, everything works fine.